# javascript | Array conversion

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array and would like to convert it to another structure.

**My array:**

```
["DZ|47", "DZ|48", "DZ|53", "DZ|57", "AR|202", "AR|206", "AR|213", "BY|484", "BY|485", "BY|487"]
```

And I would like to convert this into:

```
{"DZ":[47,48,53,57],"AR":[202,206,213],"BY":[484,485,487]}
```

I'm started to write the code, but...what next?

```
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    var idx = value.split('|');
    //arr2[idx[0]] = arr3;
});
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = {};
$.each(arr, function( index, value ) {
    var idx = value.split('|');
    if(!result[idx[0]]){
        result[idx[0]] = [];
    }
    result[idx[0]].push(idx[1]);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.prototype.reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) method:

```js
var data = ["DZ|47", "DZ|48", "DZ|53", "DZ|57", "AR|202", "AR|206", "AR|213", "BY|484", "BY|485", "BY|487"];

var result = data.reduce(function(prev, curr) {
    var split = curr.split('|');
    if (!prev[split[0]]) prev[split[0]] = [];
    prev[split[0]].push(split[1]);  
    return prev;
}, {});

alert(JSON.stringify(result));
```